# haml and ruby on rails date of birth date field syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, haml

SO I have been learning ror and trying out some form examples.
Most of the examples in the web is in erb format and my files are in .haml format. I am trying to a write a static dob field where it takes day,time,year.

```
view
%label{:for => "patient_dob"} DOB
  %date_select {Date.today,start_year => getBirthDateStart(), :end_year => getBirthDateEnd() }

module ApplicationHelper
def getBirthDateStart()
  Time.now.year - 100
end

def getBirthDateEnd()
  Time.now.year
end
end
```

I know my code doesn't make much sense, but hope it explains what I am trying to do. Can someone point me to the correct direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"%date_select" is not an HTML element. You'll use "%" to create things like %title, %p

You'll want to use "%" to create HTML directly. In this case, you'd use "%select"% to create s select box. In Ruby on Rails, you have form helper that you'll call to create collections like this.

```
=label_tag "patient_dob", "DOB"
=date_select "patient", "dob", { start_year: 100.years.ago.year, end_year: Date.today.year, default: Date.today}
```

Docs: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select

Answer (score 1):

In Haml, you use `%` to start a tag, and `=` to use a helper method like `date_select`. You could rewrite your example like this:

```
=label_tag :patient_dob, "DOB"
=date_select :patient, :dob, :start_year => 5.years.ago, :end_year => 5.years.from_now
```

A few other things:

- In Ruby, using camelCase method names (like `getBirthStartYear`) is unconventional. Stick with `snake_case`, and your code will be consistent with the rest of Rails and the Ruby community.
- It's also a good idea to drop the parenthesis `()` from method calls as well. This helps blur the line behind what is a property and what is a method, which I think encourages better internal API design. For that reason, I would also encourage you to drop the `get` in favour of something more meaningful, like `new_patient_dob_start_year`.
- Honestly, though, for the sake of simplicity and clarity, I would avoid making additional methods if there's no reason to. `5.years.ago` or `5.years.from_now` is very easy to read, and doesn't require another programmer looking up where a method is defined.

Comment: thanks for the tip.is there a way i can change the format to month day and year in the above example?

Comment: Yes. Just add an `:order => [:month, :day, :year]` option. Take a look at http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select